# pygame: using pygame.mixer simultaneously from 2 threads fails

Tags: python, pygame, audio

I am trying to build a little sound generator with pygame and numpy. The following code plays the data out of my numpy arrays correctly, but when I try to use this code in a module and access it either from different threads or from different processes to play two sounds at a time, one of the sounds is played *before* the other one instead of *both at the same time*

```
def _play_array(array, ms, vol):
    sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(_intern._as_int16(array))
    channel = sound.play(-1)
    channel.set_volume(vol)
    if ms > 50:
        pygame.time.delay(ms-50)
        channel.fadeout(50)
    else:
        pygame.time.delay(ms)
    sound.stop()
```

update:

I have tried installing audiere, but all that happens is that it comes up with a ridiculously long error traceback, but this apparently is the problem the installer encountered: `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory`

(edit)
Now I found out it does not work on Mac OS X

update 2:

trying to use snack/tkSnack: `RuntimeError: Tk not intialized or not registered with Snack`

update 3:

trying to install wxPython to play the sound after writing it to a file - `import wx` just fails: `/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core_.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper`. I am getting slightly annoyed by this problem...

**update 4:**

see post

Comment: You should check out our sister site, [Gamedev.se].

Comment: Well, this is not even about games, but thank you for posting the link, maybe ill find something there

Comment: Heh, that's what I get for looking at the tags more than the question. :) Still, they might have more pygame-related stuff there, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has become to annoying for me. I decided to use the os-wide standard music player to play it, as none of the other methods seem to work.

```
os.system("open " + path)
```

works fine on mac.

Answer (score 0):

To completely bypass your problem you could use py audiere to make your sounds. with it you could have two different tones at once.

Using your code I don't think you can have two tones at once.
This is a snippet from my frequency generator:

```
speakers = audiere.open_device()

tone = speakers.create_square(start_freq *2)
tone.pan = 1

tone.stop()
tone.play()
```

Just have two sounds instead of one.

Sorry it doesn't use your code but perhaps this could be useful to you. :)

Comment: I actually tried to install it before, but it failed to build. When looking up on the internet why this happened, I was told it does not work on mac os x. Unfortunately I am developing and testing on a mac...